# DataGridView Row Color Doesn't Change

Tags: c#, datagridview

Hello im working on Windows Form Applications but i have a problem. We are using data grid view and if row's if one column or more is empty, i want to highlight it. I dont know why but my code doesn't work. Here its my code;

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var dtCombined = PopulateCombinedDatatable();       
        dataGridView.DataSource = dtCombined;
        HighlateIfEmpty();
    }

    public string[] FindFilePath()
    {
       //OPERATIONS
    }

    public DataTable PopulateCombinedDatatable()
    {

       //MY OPERATIONS
    }

    public void HighlateIfEmpty()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if ((string)cell.Value == string.Empty)
                {
                    cell.Style.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet;
                    cell.Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Aquamarine;
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.BlueViolet;
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;
                }
            }
        }                      
    }
```

Thanks...

PS : This code finds right columns and rows but not paint it

Comment: Please call the function a little later, maybe form the FormLoad or  FormShown event

Comment: It doesnt work :(

Answer (score 2):

You should call this `HighlateIfEmpty()` in `dataGridView1_CellFormatting` event,
for your reference i added a `link` please go through it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx

Comment: But here it will be called over and over for for each cell !

Comment: Yes in `cell formatting` event it call for each cell so avoid foreach and try this,i hope it work for you.    private void dataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            if ((int)e.Value == 3)
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            if ((int)e.Value == 2)
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
}

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a bit old, but anyway . . .

On the DataGridView there is a `DefaultCellStyle`, inside this there is `SelectionBackColor` and `SelectionForeColor` properties.

The DataGridView uses a style inheritance idea, in case you find that the style you pick is not being applied.